# Can't get badge number to change when sending FCM message to iOS through API

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

all I am trying to do is change the badge number only on the ios app,
here is my json

```
{
    "registration_ids":["frsuaw....6HdPO"],
    "apns":
    {
        "payload":
        {
            "aps":
            {
                "badge":34
            }
        }
    },

    "notification":
    {
        "title":"My notification title",
        "body":"my notification body"
    }
}
```

as suggested here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms

I should say that I granted access to Notifications (Badges, Sounds, Banners), and I can change the badge from the firebase console, but not from calling the Api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I am trying to use HTTP v1 message format in legacy HTTP API. but the weird thing is when sending the push notification request to fcm API, there is no error in the response.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to put the badge inside notification, try it and it works.

```
 {
        {
        "registration_ids":["frsuaw....6HdPO"],
        "notification":
        {
            "title":"My notification title",
            "body":"my notification body",
            "badge":34
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error : `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "badge" at 'message.android.notification': Cannot find field.`

Comment: any fix? I am also facing same issue

Comment: I was trying to set the badge number only for ios apps, what you suggest will change it on all platforms :), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below: -

```
{
    {
    "registration_ids":[""],
    "notification":
    {
        "title":"notification title",
        "body":"notification body",
        "badge":"34"
    }
}
```

Badge should be string, otherwise it will show error - "**Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "badge" at 'message.android.notification': Cannot find field**"